# setInterval() is not working on herokuapp nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, setinterval, mern

I'm working on MERN stack app. I have made one setInterval() function in backend(nodejs) which calls itself every minute.
I have tasted it locally by running my app in vscode and it works fine.

```
setInterval(() => {
  bookingDetails.find({}, (err, booking) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      booking.map((b) => {
        if (
          new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0] ===
          b.startDate.toISOString().split("T")[0]
        ) {
          if (
            ("0" + new Date().getHours()).slice(-2) +
              ":" +
              ("0" + new Date().getMinutes()).slice(-2) ===
            ("0" + b.startDate.getHours()).slice(-2) +
              ":" +
              ("0" + b.startDate.getMinutes()).slice(-2)
          ) {
            vehicleSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(
              b.bookedVehicle,
              { available: false },
              (err, vehicle) => {
                if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                } else {
                  console.log("status updated of " + vehicle._id);
                }
              }
            );
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
}, 60000);
```

Here is my code. Logic is totaly fine and working excellent locally.
But, after deploy the app on `Heroku`, all things are working fine except `setInterval()` function.
Is there any other method to call some function every 1 minute or heroku doesn't allow to run setInterval() function?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Nothing on Heroku prevents `setInterval` from working, though if you request a particularly long interval it may not work as expected. Please [edit] your code into the question so we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: hey Chris, thanks for reply. I want to run setInterval() every minute.

Comment: Thank you for editing your question. Unfortunately, it still isn't clear enough. Please provide an actual code example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: hey chris, i have modified question with code. please look into it.